# angularjs with restfull webservices

Tags: angularjs

My angularjs application located in /home/scriplogix/higi/kiosk folder I have created one restfull webservie in eclipse it has generated one link http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall

Now I want to connect my local application to restfull webservice. I have two doubts

1. Is it possible to connect to local application to restfull webservice
2. I am using the code

   ```
   return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall')
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
       $window.alert('success')
       $window.alert('data'+data)
   })
   .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       $window.alert('failure');
   }); //it will work out or not
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs with restfull webservice communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579682/angularjs-with-restfull-webservice-communication)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is.
2. You are right.

However you may be need to add header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the answer from your restfull website. It is better if your angular app wil be at the same server as restfull service.

Comment: but that code is not working the status is coming as 0

Comment: where i need to place Access-Control-Allow-Origi

Comment: where i need to place Access-Control-Allow-Origi

Comment: @panduk Use Fiddler to capture traffic and check it. May be your service doesn't answer. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is custom header at server side (web-service side).